# SQL Server 2005 - SSIS validation error server-side only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dts, ssis

I am deploying some integration services into a SQL Server 2005. On my computer, I don't have any validation error but I do on the server.

It comes from an OLE DB connection manager: "Login failed for user 'rw_user'". Whereas I can fully run it on a client, the connection works perfectly.

This is a connection to the server itself.

Comment: What is the user mentioned in the error please?

Comment: @gbn I use an username I created: rw_user

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

- If you can run it locally, is it under your credentials?
- That is, have you fully permissioned rw_user on the target SQL Server?
- User/password stored OK in the package?

Comment: I can perfectly run it locally using this username and password. And yes, I checked the "save password" option in the connection manager.